# How to change private ssh key in digital ocean

Tags: ssh-keys, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

In "**cloud.digitalocean.com**" , we added ssh key when creating droplet. Now i want to change the **private SSh key** which we are using now for login to server.

I can see the private key in below places :

**1**./root/.ssh - authorized_keys [ Change ssh key in file directly ]

**2**.Login to Digital ocean account & Go to Settings & change SSh key there as below images :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the key in `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Updating the key in the DO website is relevant for new droplets you create.

Comment: thanks, in that they mentioned only `Public-Lines` , is i need to change only `Public-Lines` ? is that going to be enough , so no need to change private lines ?

Comment: I don't understand this. What does 'they mentioned only Public-Lines` mean?

Comment: when we try to connect to host through ssh, we attach ppk file in putty, in that ppk file ther are 6 public lines and 14 private lines, in `authorized_keys` file, they mentioned only public lines.....

Comment: okay, in `authorized_keys` , we need to change only public lines & we have to use new private key at the time of connecting to host through ftp or ssh......